# How to indent in TeXnicCenter?

Tags: indentation, texniccenter

I am using [TeXnicCenter](http://www.texniccenter.org/) as my LaTeX editor. My problem is with indentation. When I select text and I use `tab` the text will not be indented correctly. It will look like this:

Original text:

```
\section{Hello}
Hi, How are you? Today is my birthday
so I won't be able to come. blablabla
ablablablablablablablablablablablabla
ablablablablablablablablablablablabl.    
I am fine. Thanks. It's ok.
```

Text after indentation:

```
\section{Hello}
      Hi, How are you? Today is my birthday
so I won't be able to come. blablabla
ablablablablablablablablablablablabla
ablablablablablablablablablablablabl.    
      I am fine. Thanks. It's ok.
```

Desired text:

```
\section{Hello}
      Hi, How are you? Today is my birthday
      so I won't be able to come. blablabla
      ablablablablablablablablablablablabla
      ablablablablablablablablablablablabl.    
      I am fine. Thanks. It's ok.
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Yes you are right. You can answer it, so I can accept it. Also, do you know please how to make the indentation automatically? Because, after each indentation I do, I have to go I press `Enter` to make the indentation good.

Comment: Just FYI: http://latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=31&t=24967&p=84747#p84744

Comment: have a look at `latexindent.pl` (disclaimer: I'm the author)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the line numbers. Probably you don't have a new line and then the tab is applied only before `Hi`.

Press *Enter* after `birthday` to see if a tab will be inserted before `so`.

I don't recommend you to insert line breaks between words in a single paragraph. Let the editor do the job for you wrapping the lines.

Some editors could insert blank lines there and if you share the file with someone it could be a problem.

I recommend you to use TeXstudio. It works very well and if you indent the paragraph, the whole block containing its wrapped lines will be moved also.

Comment: »I don't recommend you to insert line breaks between words in a single paragraph« why not? I always do that and never had any problems doing so. Just because *some* editors *could* do something which *could* be a problem? Maybe TeXnicCenter doesn't do anything…

Comment: OK, but I wrote *if you share the file with someone it could be a problem*. It happened with me. I had to help a friend who were using Winedt and all the files were opened with blank lines between line breaks. The editor was bad configured and it was very hard to solve.

Comment: probably https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Common_problems but this *can* also be a problem with linebreaks in the preamble or between paragraphs (I've had such cases…)